# git find changeset between releases

Tags: git

I am looking into finding a list of commits that have been added between releases.

I drafted a script and the idea was to find the common ancestor between the two releases and list commits from there. I can see from the results that is been adding commits that are too old.

```
set -euo pipefail

git fetch origin


last_release=hotfix/x.y.z
this_release=release/t.f.g

function get_last_commit()
{

    branch=$1
    rev=$(git log -n1 origin/$branch --format=%h)
    echo >&2 "Last commit on $branch: $rev"

    echo $rev
}


export rev_develop=$(get_last_commit develop)
export rev_last=$(get_last_commit $last_release)
export rev_this=$(get_last_commit $this_release)


export common_ancestor=$(git merge-base --octopus $rev_this $rev_develop $rev_last)
echo >&2 "common ancestor: $common_ancestor"

git log --oneline $common_ancestor..$rev_this
```

Update after @torek comments:

by removig `--octopus` I can get the commits between the common ancestor and the last commit in release

and, I suppose, by adding

```
git log --oneline $common_ancestor..$rev_last
```

I can get the commit in the hotfix branch that were not merged back into develop.

Comment: Don't do `git log -n1 origin/$branch --format=%h`, do `git rev-parse origin/$branch`. (Get the full hash ID as if using `%H` format. If you really want an abbreviated hash ID, add `--short`.) Why are you using `git merge-base --octopus` here, are you planning to do an octopus merge? By the way, check the pop-up tag information for [tag:history] (hover your mouse over it, or click on it).

Comment: using `git merge-base --octopus` because I want to find the common ancestor of `develop`, `releasexxx` and `hotfix1`, because in some cases the hotfix or the release are not (unfortunatelly) back merged into develop. so looking at the history graph `merge-base` gives me the right starting point.

Comment: OK, but, `--octopus` will often add more commits that you don't want, which is what you're griping about here. So consider *not* doing that (perhaps you want to invoke `git merge-base` more than once).

Comment: you are right. removing `--octopus` gets what I hope is correct, why running `merge-base` multiple times?

Comment: If you're looking for un-applied bug fixes, you can find them with additional merge-base operations (provided there are labels for those fixes and provided you write whatever additional code is required here).